# Why are x and z evaluating differently if "x=(date<<7)>>12" and {y=date<<7;z=y>>12;}?

Tags: c, short, unsigned-integer, bit-shift

It is really frustrating.What is the possible reason that `(date<<7)>>12` is giving a different result from `y>>12` where `y` is `date<<7`?.I should add that the latter is working correctly as I intend,but the first is not.What's the difference?I can see none.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
unsigned short date=5225,x,y,z;
x=(date<<7)>>12;
printf("Month is %hu\n",x);
y=date<<7;
z=y>>12;
printf("Month is %hu\n",z);

}
```

**OUTPUT**

`Month is 163`

`Month is 3`

Comment: @Robᵩ I have declared y as `unsigned short` and then initialized it to `date<<7`.How is it undefined still?

Comment: You could try it like this: `((unsigned short)(date<<7))>>12`

Comment: @A4L It works.I would like you to add a line about why it works.I've asked kenny too,just to be sure.

Comment: Well i would say intuitively if only `date` is casted to `unsigned short` - witch is actually obsolete since date is already of that type - then the result is casted again to `int` witch has the same effect as no cast at all, this is what Kenny explained about integer promotion. So what you need is actually to cast the final result i.e. `(date<<7)` so that it becomes `unsigned short` again then apply `>>12` to it.

Comment: @A4L Why does `x = (unsigned short)(date << 7) >> 12` solve the problem then?

Comment: @A4L I think you misread my comment.I am not casting `date` alone, but `date<<7`.It solves the problem.Can you explain why?

Comment: No i didn't misread your comment, i was just having Armen's answer `((unsigned short)date<<7)>>12` in mind while writing, witch casts only `date` not `date<<7`, see my comment there.

Comment: @A4L So `x = (unsigned short)(date << 7) >> 12` solves the problem right?(It does,I tested).If yes,can you add a line why?

Comment: I did add line as for why, see my second comment on your question ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, all integer computations are promoted to at least `int`<sup>1</sup>. So

```
x = (date << 7) >> 12
  = (5225 << 7 /* result as int */) >> 12
  = 668800 >> 12
  = 163
```

after the computation is complete, we truncate the result back to an `unsigned short` to get 163.

In the second case, the `y` forced the result to be truncated to be an `unsigned short`, so

```
y = (unsigned short) (date << 7)
  = (unsigned short) 668800
  = 13440
z = y >> 12
  = 3
```

<sup>1</sup>: C11 §6.5.7/3: "The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand."; §6.3.1.1/2: "If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*."

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: Yes. The parenthesis doesn't change the promotion rules.

Comment: `x = (unsigned short)(date << 7) >> 12` solves the problem.I intuitively know why,but I would like you to explain in a nutshell through a comment,just to be sure.

Comment: Why does `x = (unsigned short)(date << 7) >> 12` solve the problem?**A4L** says this casting has no effect.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: A4L says casting has no effect because that answer is casting the `date` variable only, which changes nothing. You are casting the result of `(date << 7)`.